# List scroll isn't functioning

Tags: swift, swiftui

I made a view that had a List of Books, with the picture of the book as thumbnails. Some of the List is longer than the emulator screen so you cant see the full list. From some of the docs and what I searched Lists should be scrollable. When I put the list in a scroll view it doesn't show the list properly anymore.

```
        NavigationStack{
            HStack{
                Image("quest_logo1").resizable().frame(width: 60, height: 45)
                Text("Currently Reading").fontWeight(.semibold)
                
            }
            List (currents) { current in
                HStack{
                    Image(current.img)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 90, height: 140)
                    
                    VStack{
                        Text("\(current.title) \(current.act)").padding(10).fontWeight(.light)
                    }
                }
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .background(.teal.opacity(0.4))
        }
```

I tried nesting the List into a ScrollView to make it scrollable, but that didn't resolve it.

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: Remove the space character after „List“.

Comment: A list inside scrollview doesn't work in SwiftUI

Comment: The code that you show works well for me in my tests. The `List`
 scrolls by itself, **do not** put it inside a `ScrollView`.
If your `List` does not scroll, it is probably due to other code that you are not showing us.
 Show the full code that makes your `List` not scroll. As mentioned show a minimal reproducible example code.